# Open-source manga making software

Tags: windows, open-source, image-editor, graphic-design

I am not very special at drawing stuff, but I want to create my own manga novel.

So, is there an open-source manga making software? If yes, please recommend it.

I am using Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for something to do the drawing for you I think you are out of luck but you might like to take a look at [Krita](https://krita.org/).

- Free (Gratis)
- Open Source
- Cross Platform, (now including Win8.1).
- Lots of online tutorials, including some specific to comics/graphic novels.
- Interfaces with a number of **graphics tablets** and works really well with them, **but** no so easy to get good results without one so I would strongly suggest  investing in one, *thanks to Oxinabox for reminding me that I meant to mention this*. To quote the web page:

> Krita isn’t much fun without a pressure sensitive tablet. If the tablet has been properly configured, Krita works with Wacom, Huion and other uc-logic based tablets, on Windows and Linux (...). Genius tablets are know to have problems.

There is even a Manga Template:
[image: CreateManga]

Some examples from the web site:
[image: alex-sabo][image: girl-to-protect-the-sleep]

Comment: I have used Krita, and found that it is practically impossible to use without a graphics tablet.  If you found it the same, you might want to enhance your answer by mentioning this.
(To be fair, one shouldn't be considering drawing a manga on PC without one)